# How to rotate all bones at the same time?

Tags: python, bones

So I have a funtion that sets rotation according to the world frame of reference and it works fine. But when I try to set rotation for multiple bones e.g in an arm, it doesn't do so at the same time but rather one by one when played in a loop. For example, first goes arm then forearm then wrist. Here I rotate the arm to vertical position and have to run the script 3 times to do so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the function I use to rotate the bones:

```
def setRotation(bone, quaternion, global_offset, local_offset):
    # Extract quaternion coordinates
    w, x, y, z = quaternion
    # Create quaternion matrix based on given coordinates.
    rotation = Quaternion([w, x, y, z]).to_matrix().to_4x4()


    # Create quaternion offset matrix based on Euler coordinates.
    offset_matrix  = Euler([radians(global_offset[0]), radians(global_offset[1]), radians(global_offset[2])]).to_quaternion().to_matrix().to_4x4()

    # Decompose current bone matrix to get it's location, rotation(not needed) and scale vectors.
    location, _, scale = bone.matrix.decompose()
    scale = Vector([1,1,1])

    local_offset_matrix = rotation @ Euler([radians(local_offset[0]), radians(local_offset[1]), radians(local_offset[2])]).to_quaternion().to_matrix().to_4x4()

    # Express as matrix
    location_matrix = Matrix.Translation(location)
    rotation_matrix = offset_matrix @ local_offset_matrix
    scale_matrix = Matrix.Scale(scale[0],4,(1,0,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(scale[1],4,(0,1,0)) @ Matrix.Scale(scale[2],4,(0,0,1))


    # Join location, new rotation and scale matrices back together and assign it to the bone.
    bone.matrix = location_matrix @ rotation_matrix @ scale_matrix
    bone.scale[0] = 1
    bone.scale[1] = 1
    bone.scale[2] = 1
```

In the code I call it like this. But I have to run the code 3 times for it to actually rotate well

```
bones = bpy.data.objects['MHXX'].pose.bones

##Right Arm
upperArmRight = bones["upper_arm_fk.R"]
forearmRight = bones["forearm_fk.R"]
wristRight = bones["hand_fk.R"]

# Rotate
setRotation(upperArmRight, [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [-90, 0, 145])
setRotation(forearmRight, [1, 0, 0, 0], [-7, 0, 0], [-90, 0, 145])
setRotation(wristRight, [1, 0, 0, 0], [-7, 0, 0], [-90, 0, 155])
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong and how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: PS. For anyone wondering why do I need 3 rotations instead of one: quaternion is for mpu sensor, global_offset is for offseting quaternion axis, local_offset is for initial rotation(without affecting the axis). Wanted to get that out of the way but I don't think it really matters for this problem.

Comment: Hi. You can always edit your original question by using the edit link below it, if you want to expand the scope. No need to put it in the comments where it might get lost due to sorting.

Comment: Quite likely needs a `depsgraph.update()` or some such at end of method to update bone matrices. (explains the run 3 times).  `Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4()` is a quick way to create a scale matrix from a vector.